# Bouncy Castle C# library - Java to C# Encryption with PKCS8 and RSA

Tags: c#

I need to convert a little piece of code about encryption from Java To C#.
I've found  Bouncy Castle C# library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/) but, I've not found C# equivalent code to:

```
java.security.PrivateKey privatekey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new    
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(PRIVATE_RSA_KEY));//PRIVATE_RSA_KEY is a byte array
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(2, privatekey);
(...)
cipher.doFinal(examPrivateKey, k, l); //k and l are integers
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: How much C# do you know? Have you looked up how to create Private keys in C#?

Comment: Hello. I'm not a beginner in C# but I'm not used to use this Kind of Encyption algorithms...I've read documentation about encryption but I couldn't make strictly the link with this Java code.         Step 1): generate a private key from a byte array with specific algorithm - Step 2) ??